# How can I grant view only privileges to all the packages and procedure in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I would like to grant `readonly` privileges to all the packages that I have in `Oracle` but not sure how to do so.

I have following command that grants select privilege to one of the user on a table.

```
grant select on scott.dept to app_user_ro;
```

I have bunch of `packages` that contains lot of `stored procedures` in it.

Is it possible to grant `read only` privileges to all these `packages`? If so, is this the correct command to do so?

```
grant select on scott.dept_package.* to app_user_ro;
grant select on scott.employee_package.* to app_user_ro;
..
..
some more here
```

Is there a way to grant `read only` privileges to all the packages in a single shot ?

Comment: It is unclear what you mean when you say "read-only to a package". What are you expecting the recipient of this privilege to see or do?

Comment: A user with execute privileges on a package will be able to do anything the package code does. There is no "read only" option other than writing the package to contain only "read only" code in the first place, nor can you grant different privileges to different functions or procedures within a package.

Answer (score -1):

A user can only be granted "EXECUTE" privileges on a package, in its entirety:

```
grant execute on scott.dept_package to app_user_ro;
```

Once granted, a user with execute privileges on the package will be able to do anything the package code does. If the package has procedures with definer's rights (the default) that insert, update, or delete rows in a table, then the user will be able to perform those activities through the package regardless of their individual privileges on the application tables.

There is no "read only" option other than writing the package to contain only "read only" code in the first place. You must ensure that the package code contains no DML code with definer's rights, but rather uses invoker's rights that are dependent on the user's individual privileges on objects referred to in the code.

See these links for more info on definer's and invoker's rights and how to manage them:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/managing-security-for-definers-rights-and-invokers-rights.html#GUID-EF625176-A3AA-47F5-BAEE-248DBAAF22A3
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/control-invoker-rights-privileges-for-plsql-code-12cr1